# Vite 4 fails to emit JS bundle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, rollup

I have upgraded from [Vite](https://vitejs.dev) `2.9.13` to `4.0.4`, and to be on theme with the version number Vite can not find the entry point for JS anymore. It emits everything correctly except the JavaScript bundle which ends up like below. No error messages or anything.

```js
// main-12345678.js

import "./reset-12345678.js";
const customfonts = "";
const style = "";
//# sourceMappingURL=main-12345678.js.map

// Where is the rest of my bundle? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```

Any ideas as to why I get a blank page and the almost empty JS bundle above?

```bash
vite --mode staging --config vite.config.js build
```

```js
// vite.config.js

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => ({
  plugins: [react()],

  root: "client",

  build: {
    sourcemap: mode !== "production",
    minify: mode !== 'production' ? false : 'esbuild',

    outDir: "dist/publish",
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: new URL("./client/index.html", import.meta.url).pathname,
        other: new URL("./client/other.html", import.meta.url).pathname,
      },
    },
  },
}));
```